# MongoDB group by url origin from full URLs?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of docs, 1 attribute is a full URL eg:

```
{ "url" : "https://someurl.com/somepath"}
{ "url" : "https://otherurl.com/somepath"}
{ "url" : "https://someurl.com/somepath"}
{ "url" : "https://someurl.com/somepath"}
```

How can I group by origin, ie to return someurl and other url?

(i have over half a million records to query)

Comment: Best way is to split the URL before writing the document and store/index the parts you need in a separate field.  If you don't then a full collection scan will be performed each time you need to group/count/find/whatever on that part of the URL.

Comment: dang yea i though that would be the answer, ok thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the idea is to:

1. Split the URL using [$split](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/split/).
2. Pick the origin at index `2`.
3. group it using `$group`
   Try this:

```js
db.testCollection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            origin: {
                $arrayElemAt: [{ $split: ["$url", "/"] }, 2]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$origin",
            result: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
        }
    }
])
```

Output

```js
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "someurl.com",
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("606718b9696d491d3c562c62"),
            "url" : "https://someurl.com/somepath",
            "origin" : "someurl.com"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("606718b9696d491d3c562c64"),
            "url" : "https://someurl.com/somepath",
            "origin" : "someurl.com"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("606718b9696d491d3c562c65"),
            "url" : "https://someurl.com/somepath",
            "origin" : "someurl.com"
        }
    ]
},

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "otherurl.com",
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("606718b9696d491d3c562c63"),
            "url" : "https://otherurl.com/somepath",
            "origin" : "otherurl.com"
        }
    ]
}
```